# /opt/BitDefender/bin/notify_script.sh failed: exit code 2 on CentOS 6

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I'm running CentOS 6.10 and everytime that I run a command I got this message on the console
`/opt/BitDefender/bin/notify_script.sh failed: exit code 2`
I do not have Bitdefender install so I guess it's ok to fail something that is not there.

My question is, where is this message coming from? how can I find whoever is doing this and stopped it? this message is really annoying.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you *sure* you don't have it installed? A good starting point would probably be your cronjobs.

Comment: Yeah. I don't have any crontab that does this. I also don't have a `BitDefender` folder inside `/opt`. I guess that at some point someone install it and then remove it. But I'm not sure how to get rid of that message. I don't know what is generating that message in the first place.